# Why does this input pattern not work?

Tags: html

I'm using the html5 input pattern attribute to check for a time in HH:MM AM or HH:MM PM format.  The inout control is coded like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="ConcertTime" name="ConcertStartTime" type="text" pattern="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$" title="hh:mm AM/PM" required placeholder="hh:mm AM/PM">
```

After keying in something which doesn't match the pattern and clicking the Submit button, no error is flagged. Other validation attributes (e.g. the "required" on this input) are correctly handled.

I've tried the regex in various regex test programs and it successfully detects valid and invalid time formats.

This is in Chrome 62.0.3202.94

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  The js console reveals that html doesn't like the \040 in the regex, thinks it is an invalid sequence.  Replaced it with a space character and all now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of that but I believe Safari doesn't support it so I would need a pattern check anyway.